# Can we send push notifications between two apps using quickblox?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

In my application, I am using Quick blox for chat and push notifications. I have two applications agentapp and seeker app. Can I send push notifications through Quick blox between these two apps as I've added only one app over quickblox.

Comment: Quick blox should already implement this for you, push notification is sent by cloud services.

Comment: Were you able to make the Quickblox chat(and chat's APNS) work in two iPhone apps using a single Quickblox application?

I too am in exactly same situation. Can you please share the Info on what procedure you followed now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBlox has functionality to send pushnotifications and chat messages per application.

Two QuickBlox applications are not connected and Chat is set per application.

Also, [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/Push_notifications#Chat:_Incoming_message_alerts_.28push_notifications.29_for_offline_users) is information on how to setup automatic push notifications for offline users.

Thanks.