# Quickblox IOS cross-application chat integration

Tags: ios, quickblox

We are trying to integrate Quickblox with our two of our mobile (iPhone) apps .
The scenario is:

1. We have a mobile app that is used by contractors.
2. We have another mobile app that is used by customers

The contractors need to chat from their version of the app with the customer who are using their app.

Is there a way to integrate the chat between these two apps? Both the apps hit the same back-end database.

As I understand, in case of iPhone apps, we have a certificate + profile setup (from Apple developer account) which is uploaded to Quickblox to send APNS.
Since this involves two apps, we will have two sets of certificates. Does Quickblox support this multiple certificates for sending APNS across the apps?

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to connect QuickBlox application with your own application you should have your custom server in the middle which will translate requests from your application to QB app and back.
2. How to setup [APNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767227/can-we-send-push-notifications-between-two-apps-using-quickblox/35772220#35772220)
3. QuickBlox has support for 2 APNS certificates: development and production